# How should I read the voltage ratings on this terminal strip?

Tags: voltage, datasheet, ratings, wire-terminals

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/63479.pdf
[image]

I don't understand the voltage ratings given. On the far left, it looks like four different voltage ratings. Is there some way to tell which ones are applicable under what circumstances?

Comment: As I'm seeing it, what matters is the pin spacing, so basicaly if your pins are farther away from each other, you can use the higher voltage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a bad form of technical documentation - too terse to be easily comprehensible. So what I did was to go to the manufacturer's site (Wago) and looked at the tabular form of specifications in their [catalog](http://eshop.wago.com/JPBC/index.jsp?loginname=GuestUser&COMPANYID=Guests&TERRITORY=ALL&LANGUAGE=EN&FUNCTION=VIEWCATGROUP&catalogidentifier=WAGO31&HOOK_URL&intLogin=1) (search for 236-102). Another helpful clue is the vertical line separating two voltage ratings which matches the split between metric and AWG. It turned out the split is also for two separate ratings depending on the certifying authority. So here's what those numbers would mean:

On left side: [Rated Voltage]/[Rated Surge Voltage]/[Applicable Environment/Pollution Category], [Nominal Current]

These ratings are based on IEC/EN 60664-1. As the standard is only available for a fee, here's a [handy guide](http://www.denverpels.org/Downloads/Denver_PELS_20090915_Aldous_Insulation_Coordination.pdf) on Pollution Categories. Also, here's Wago's [detail sheet](http://www.wago.com/cms/doc/electrical_tests.pdf) on test methods and parameters.

On right side: [Rated Voltage], [Nominal Current] [Certification]

Thus for [CSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Standards_Association), the certified ratings are 300V and 15A.